# Neighbourhood Of Any Point

Tags: limits

What does it mean to say that $x \to c$, can $x$ and $c$ be both variables, can $x$ and $c$ be both constants?

Comment: In what [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19747/what-do-we-mean-by-context) does this appear in? I'm guessing this is calculus.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context, but generally $x$ is a variable and $c$ is a fixed constant.

As $x \to c$ means as $x$ approaches $c$, probably from all directions in $2$ dimensions given the title.